# Probability of rolling a dice

Tags: probability

[image]

I came across this example question. I understand most part except $E[f(0)] =6.15$.

For the initial roll, shouldn't you have

$E[X] = 1/6 *( 1+ 2+ 3+ 4+5) =2.5$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$E[f(0)]$ is the expectation of the whole run if you start with $0$.  Your calculation is the expectation of the amount you have after one roll, but $E[f(0)]$ is the expectation after all the rolls until you quit or roll a $6$.  Once you have decided to stop if the total is $15$ or more, your expectation for any number above $15$ is that number, as is shown in the table.  You can then calculate the expectation if you have $14$, which is $0$ if you roll a $6$ and $16.5$ if you don't.  This averages out to $14\frac 16$.  You keep computing downward and find your expectation at the start is $6.15$

Comment: Can you show me a sample calculation for 0 ?

Comment: It is just $\frac 16(f(1)+f(2)+\ldots f(5))$ where the values are in the table.  You are calculating down from the top.  If you start with $0$ you have $\frac 16$ chance to roll $1,2,3,4,5$ and have the expectation above and $\frac 16$ chance to roll $6$ and wind up with nothing.

Comment: But then how do I know $f(1)$?

Comment: You have to calculated downward from $f(15)$ through $f(19)$.  Because you stop rolling if you get to $15$, those are easy.  Then you compute $f(14)$, then $f(13)$ and so on.  See if you can duplicate $f(14)$ from the formula.

Comment: Exactly, you start calculating from $f(14) $.